# What's really the difference in these two Doctrine mappings?

Tags: database-design, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, associations

A `Product` may have zero or more `Label`. A `Label` can be assigned to zero or more `Product`. So, what's the difference between **mapping A** and **mapping B** in Doctrine?

### Mapping A (OneToMany - ManyToOne)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Label", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected $labels;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="label")
 */
class Label
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="labels")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

### Mapping B (ManyToMany - ManyToMany) [documentation example](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Label", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected $labels;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="label")
 */
class Label
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="labels")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example you try to match a ONE-TO-MANY relation to a MANY-TO-MANY relation. This will cause problems when trying to access the labels of a product. It will try to find the relation in a column in the label table. While a many-to-many relation should have an extra table that couples the two entities.

This is pure theoretically. I didn't try it with real code, but I suppose Doctrine will throw an exception if you use the first example. I fact the first example should not be used.

If you're not familiair with different types of relations read some articles about RDBMS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model